# Visual Studio code Django Python debugger points to an older virtualenv

Tags: python, django, debugging, visual-studio-code

I was having some issues with my .virtualenv folders (had 2 projects working in parallel, and one virtual environment was looking at the other), so I manually deleted them and re-did a pipenv/pip install of just 1 project. I verified that the new folders for the same project got created. However, when I try to debug the project using Visual Studio Code, it gives me this error:

```
& : The term 'C:\Users\userId\.virtualenvs\project-1abcde2S\Scripts\python.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name,
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Where the project-1abcde2S points to the folders I deleted. Is there anyway to ensure that new virtual environments get picked up in Visual Studio code? any other tips on debugging a Django project would be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you first select an environment for a workspace it gets written to your `.vscode/settings.json` configuration file. It sounds like you just need to update that setting by [selecting your new environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-an-environment).